# SVN server host os

Tags: windows, linux, svn

Recently I was searching on how to secure svn repository, or otherwords how to enable ssl connection to svn repository for a windows server 2003. Does it make more sense to use Linux server instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Windows, take a look at [**VisualSVN server**](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). It's a wrapper around "real" SVN, and setting it up to accept only SSL connections is a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It really comes down to which OS are you most comfortable (best able to) administer?  My experience is that Subversion works fine with both Windows and Linux.

As Pekka points out, [VisualSVN server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) makes the set up very easy.